# Distribution of k'th squared singular value of a Gaussian matrix?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-matrices

Suppose I sample $m\times n$ matrix $X$ with IID entries sampled from standard Gaussian and $m,n$ are both large. What is the distribution of $k$th squared singular value?

I simulated singular values from some 100x100 random matrices below. Means of these seem to be well predicted by Marchenko-Pastur distribution with shape parameter 1. What about the variances?

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-distribution-kth-eig.nb)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for the top eigenvalue, distribution approaches Tracy-Widom ([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-distribution-kth-eig.nb))

[image]